# App script gives error=TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') onEdit @ Code.gs:3

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get the following to work. In my Google sheet, I have two columns PerDag and RPerDag.

Perdag uses a formula that is inserted when I add value from my private app, then I need to auto-copy PerDag to RPerDag, but it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') onEdit    @ Code.gs:3
```

I cannot figure out why it won't work.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Eenhede" && e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
      var row = e.range.getRow();
      var value = e.range.getValue();
      sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(value);
  }
}
```

I also get this when trying to debug:

```
e:  undefined
sheet:  undefined
row: undefined
value: undefined
```

I did try to debug, but no luck in getting it to work.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have an app that calls `onEdit(e)` and , as the [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions): `Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run`. The error that you are getting is consistent with running 'onEdit' from the Script Editor rather than it being triggered by a user edit.